# Why there is a delay when I install app from play store on my pc

Tags: applications, google-play-store

When I install any app from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store) from pc, it wont install soon. I need to click 2 or 3 times install to install the app in my phone.

But when I click install it will show as installed but it is not. I need to click install again so the app will get downloaded to my phone.

I use Google play from pc as my mobile screen is small (Xperia U) so that I can read the description and reviews easily than from my mobile. But the delay is killing me.

My pc and phone are connected to different network (I use mobile data in my phone). But I tried with same network also, but still the delay is there.

Any idea? Only me facing this issue or its for everyone?

Comment: How long a delay are you talking about? A few seconds, or some hours?

Comment: 5 to 10 mins of delay

Comment: A few seconds is normal.

Comment: @DanHulme but it is taking 10 minutes to start